# Would sleeping on floor tiles make my cat catch cold?

Tags: cats, veterinarian, sleep

My cat sleeps on he floor tiles a lot. I assume she wants to cool herself.

But I was concerned if doing that frequently would make her catch cold.

And if she is already sick (possibly cold), would sleeping on the floor make her sickness worse?

Comment: Cold as in a virus infection? E.g. rhinovirus?

Comment: The only thing "cold temperatures" and "a cold" have in common is sharing a name. The connection between them is about the same as "a caterpillar" (insect that metamorphoses into a butterfly or moth) and "a Caterpillar" (heavy construction equipment).

Comment: In Germany also the people say "if you get too cold you will catch a cold more easily" So I think this is a real question, even if it is more like a myth. Will getting a low temperature of body increase the risk to catch a cold? And would sleeping onto the floor even decrease the temperature of the body?

Comment: @sthephie , Allison,  I understand what you are saying. I know being cold does not equal catching cold. But being too cold for a long time or a sudden drop in temperature could potentially *induce* cold right? It's kinda immune_system-virus related. (in other words, weakens the immune system and/or make it easier for viruses to "win") Like if you took a hot shower then went out straight to the open cold air, that could lead to you catching cold right? Or the reason we easily catch cold in winter. This is what I'm referring to.

Comment: @Allerleirauh , yes that's a simpler way to iterate my question. Thank you.

Comment: This is mostly me guessing, but tile probably won't feel as cold to a cat as it does to humans because they're covered in fur. Like how if you walked on the tile in socks, it doesn't really feel that cold through the socks. Also, I would expect most cats to be sensible enough to go to someplace warmer if they're even unpleasantly cool, let alone cold enough that they could stress the immune system or something.

Comment: The "reason we catch cold in winter" is because indoor air becomes dryer, allowing cold viruses to transmit more easily. In humid air, droplets with viruses are more likely to precipitate out, but in dry air they stay airborne, increasing the chances for us to breathe them in. https://www.bbc.com/future/article/20151016-the-real-reason-germs-spread-in-the-winter

Comment: @Kai Yeah I totally get that but fur and socks are kinda different i guess. Also, I do believe they are sensible enough to decide that but I was concerned to why she got sick. So i was trying to rule out the causes.

Comment: @LShaver Ok that's interesting. But is that the only reason? If you took a hot steamy shower, then went outside with windows open/ac on etc, won't that make you sick?

Comment: @RooTenshi it's not the only reason; the other key contributor is that people tend to stay indoors more during the winter, breathing the same air (instead of bringing in/breathing fresh air from outdoors), allowing any small amount of contagion to circulate and stay in that environment. Switching between temperatures does not make you sick.

Comment: ok thank you for explaining

Answer (score 3):

Young kittens (below about four weeks old) can't regulate their body temperature on their own, and disease or rather-extreme old age can create issues in some cats, but most cats mostly do fine on their own here.  (I had a foster kitten that was right around 3-4 weeks that for some reason went to sleep on a cold tile floor—her mom didn't come and get her—and got very lethargic, but I found her in plenty of time and warmed her up and then she was fine.)

Regarding all the comments: sudden temperature changes count as stress, and repeated stress weakens immune responses.  However, stress, when not too severe and not continuous, also *strengthens* immune responses.  For this particular case it's probably a wash (equally helpful and hurtful).

As [Allison C said](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/33054/would-sleeping-on-floor-tiles-make-my-cat-catch-cold#comment44676_33054), the whole "staying indoors" (and often in close physical contact) is more important to the spread of various viruses and other diseases.  Put simply, when we're all locked in with each other, we get each other's colds.

(This same rule applies to cats in crowded shelters, which is why it's good to avoid this kind of crowding.)

Comment: oh ok that's a very good explanation. thank you so much that was helpful